# how to insert skills for users with laravel

Tags: laravel, many-to-many

I have a (skills) table and (users) table, and I have created (skill_user) table as a pivot,

but my problem is how can I let the user insert any skills he wants, and at the same time it is many to many relationships, which means the user should select the skills which already exist? i cannot understand how can I fix this issue?

Answer (score 0):

There are [3 methods](https://laravel.com/docs/9.x/eloquent-relationships#attaching-detaching) to work with many-to-many relationships:

1. `attach`
2. `detach`
3. `sync`.

I would say `sync` is more suitable for your case: user selects a list of skills, and you save only these. This also allows to remove skills if user unselected one.

Comment: thanks, but i know that, my question is about how to insert these skills? i mean I cannot add all skills in the world in my table manually, user should add his skills? or what?